# How to drop all rows before a specific word except the last row in a dataframe to calculate the "delta"

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a dataframe containing [3599 rows x 5 columns]. I need to drop all rows before a specific word except the last row in a dataframe to calculate the "delta". This is an example of the dataframe that I have:

```
df = 
             daytime       ProductCase       timestamp           delta 
 
0     2020-01-01 00:00:01    Product  2020-01-01 00:00:01             NaT   

1     2020-01-01 00:00:02    Product  2020-01-01 00:00:02 0 days 00:00:01   

2     2020-01-01 00:00:03    Product  2020-01-01 00:00:03 0 days 00:00:01   

3     2020-01-01 00:00:04    NoProduct  2020-01-01 00:00:04 0 days 00:00:01   

4     2020-01-01 00:00:05    NoProduct  2020-01-01 00:00:05 0 days 00:00:01  

5     2020-01-01 00:00:06    NoProduct  2020-01-01 00:00:06 0 days 00:00:01   

6     2020-01-01 00:00:07    NoProduct 2020-01-01 00:00:07 0 days 00:00:01

7     2020-01-01 00:00:08    Product  2020-01-01 00:00:08 0 days 00:00:01   

8     2020-01-01 00:00:09    Product  2020-01-01 00:00:09 0 days 00:00:01   

9     2020-01-01 00:00:10    NoProduct  2020-01-01 00:00:10 0 days 00:00:01  

10     2020-01-01 00:00:11    NoProduct  2020-01-01 00:00:11 0 days 00:00:01   

11     2020-01-01 00:00:12    NoProduct 2020-01-01 00:00:12 0 days 00:00:01 

12     2020-01-01 00:00:13    NoProduct 2020-01-01 00:00:13 0 days 00:00:01 

13     2020-01-01 00:00:14    NoProduct 2020-01-01 00:00:14 0 days 00:00:01 

      time  

0      NaN  

1      1.0  

2      1.0  

3      1.0  

4      1.0  

5      1.0  

6      1.0  

7      1.0

8      1.0  

9      1.0  

10      1.0    

11      1.0  

12     1.0 

13     1.0
```

I would like to know how to drop out all rows containing "NoProduct" except the last row with calculating the delta to get the dataframe below.

```
             daytime       ProductCase       timestamp           delta  
0     2020-01-01 00:00:01    Product  2020-01-01 00:00:01             NaT   

1     2020-01-01 00:00:02    Product  2020-01-01 00:00:02 0 days 00:00:01   

2     2020-01-01 00:00:03    Product  2020-01-01 00:00:03 0 days 00:00:01   

3     2020-01-01 00:00:07    NoProduct 2020-01-01 00:00:07 0 days 00:00:04

4     2020-01-01 00:00:08    Product  2020-01-01 00:00:08 0 days 00:00:01   

5     2020-01-01 00:00:09    Product  2020-01-01 00:00:09 0 days 00:00:01   

6     2020-01-01 00:00:14    NoProduct 2020-01-01 00:00:14 0 days 00:00:05 


      time  

0      NaN  

1      1.0  

2      1.0  

3      4.0  

4      1.0  

5      1.0  

6      5.0
```

Comment: I would like to know if my question is clear to you? If not please let me know. I need really your help.

Comment: It will be better if your dataframe was not splitted into multiple lines. Try something: `print(df.to_string(index=False))`

Comment: I need to find out the delta which is the difference in time taking with no production so I need to drop out all rows where there is no production (NoProduct) from the datafeame except the last row  and the time where there is production "Product". This information is very important to the owner of the factory to know how much time over the shift with no production.

Comment: Thanks for interest. I followed what I did, but still have the same problem.

Comment: Please let me know if that is clear to you now.

Comment: It's not a solution. It's for a better formatting of your data. Your dataframe is hard to reproduce.

Comment: ok, I will my question is more clear and edit the question again.

Comment: I would like to know if my question is more clear to you now. This is just a sample of the dataframe. My dataframe contains thousands of rows. Hope I understand what you mean regarding to data formatting.

Comment: I fully understand what you want. You want to drop all NoProduct rows except the last one followed by a Product row.

Comment: Yes, that exactly what I want. Can you give me some help to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To drop all 'NoProduct' rows except the last one followed by a 'Product' row, use a binary mask:

```
# Ensure dtypes are corrects
df['daytime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['daytime'])
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])
df['delta'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['delta'])

# Create the boolean mask
m1 = df['ProductCase'].eq('Product')
m2 = df['ProductCase'].eq('NoProduct') \
         .eq(df['ProductCase'].shift(-1, fill_value='Product').eq('Product'))
mask = m1 | m2

# Do a copy of selected rows
out = df[mask].copy()

# Updates column values
out['delta'] = out['timestamp'].diff()
out['time'] = out['delta'].dt.total_seconds()
```

Output:

```
               daytime ProductCase           timestamp           delta  time
0  2020-01-01 00:00:01     Product 2020-01-01 00:00:01             NaT   NaN
1  2020-01-01 00:00:02     Product 2020-01-01 00:00:02 0 days 00:00:01   1.0
2  2020-01-01 00:00:03     Product 2020-01-01 00:00:03 0 days 00:00:01   1.0
6  2020-01-01 00:00:07   NoProduct 2020-01-01 00:00:07 0 days 00:00:04   4.0
7  2020-01-01 00:00:08     Product 2020-01-01 00:00:08 0 days 00:00:01   1.0
8  2020-01-01 00:00:09     Product 2020-01-01 00:00:09 0 days 00:00:01   1.0
13 2020-01-01 00:00:14   NoProduct 2020-01-01 00:00:14 0 days 00:00:05   5.0
```

Details:

```
>>> pd.concat([df['ProductCase'], mask.rename('m1|m2'), 
               m1.rename('m1'), m2.rename('m2')], axis=1)

   ProductCase  m1|m2     m1     m2
0      Product   True   True  False  # m1, keep ('Product')
1      Product   True   True  False  # m1, keep ('Product')
2      Product   True   True   True  # m1, keep ('Product')
3    NoProduct  False  False  False
4    NoProduct  False  False  False
5    NoProduct  False  False  False
6    NoProduct   True  False   True  # m2, keep (followed by 'Product')
7      Product   True   True  False  # m1, keep ('Product')
8      Product   True   True   True  # m1, keep ('Product')
9    NoProduct  False  False  False
10   NoProduct  False  False  False
11   NoProduct  False  False  False
12   NoProduct  False  False  False
13   NoProduct   True  False   True  # m2, Special case of 'shift'
```

For the special case, use `fill_value='Product'` to create a virtual row (idx 14) when shifting to ensure it will always be kept.

Comment: Thank you so much for your great help much appreciated. I would like to know if you can send me a document or a link let me understand more what you did.

Comment: What part of the code you don't understand?